# nginx configuration for cakephp3 on openshift

Tags: php, cakephp, nginx, openshift, cakephp-3.0

well for use cakephp 3 I need a version of php >=5.5.9. I use as host openshift, for be more specific I am using two cartridge the first for nginx and the second for php:

1. [cartridge for nginx I choise version 1.6](https://github.com/boekkooi/openshift-cartridge-nginx)
2. [cartridge for php I choise version 5.6](https://github.com/boekkooi/openshift-cartridge-php)

nginx, on my configuration of cakephp 3 I am using the next:

```
server {
    listen  <%= ENV['OPENSHIFT_NGINX_IP'] %>:<%= ENV['OPENSHIFT_NGINX_PORT'] %>;
    root    <%= ENV['OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR'] %>/public/app/webroot;

    location / {
        index       index.html index.htm index.php ;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
      fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
      fastcgi_pass unix:<%= ENV['OPENSHIFT_PHP_SOCKET'] %>;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
      include <%= ENV['OPENSHIFT_NGINX_DIR'] %>/usr/nginx-<%= ENV['OPENSHIFT_NGINX_VERSION'] %>/conf/fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

well I just need to show me the home screen of cake php 3 without these errors are not well where failure. in my .gitignore I have this:

```
/tmp/*
/logs/*
```

[image: here the problem]

also I put these 2 guides that follow to configure nginx:

- http://liaosankai.logdown.com/
- https://djordjekovacevic.com/articles/run-laravel-5.1-on-openshift

Answer (score 0):

Well after of something hours I give a solution, with this cake php 3 work fine:

```
server {
  listen  <%= ENV['OPENSHIFT_NGINX_IP'] %>:<%= ENV['OPENSHIFT_NGINX_PORT'] %>;
  root    <%= ENV['OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR'] %>/public/app/webroot;

  location / {
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    if (-f $request_filename) {
      break;
    }

    if (-d $request_filename) {
      break;
    }

    rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.php?url=$1 last;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass unix:<%= ENV['OPENSHIFT_PHP_SOCKET'] %>;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME <%= ENV['OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR'] %>/public/app/webroot$fastcgi_script_name;
    include <%= ENV['OPENSHIFT_NGINX_DIR'] %>/usr/nginx-<%= ENV['OPENSHIFT_NGINX_VERSION'] %>/conf/fastcgi_params;
  }
}
```